# Copy large Table from Teradata to Hadoop- Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata

Im trying to create a copy of a large table in Teradata into Hive (Hadoop).
Sqoop is not an ideal solution because the size of the table is roughly 1.2 Petabytes.

My solution: Copy the data based on monthly timespan.
Issue: Data from 2006 so for each year, the script runs 12 times

I'm looking for copying the data in one go without having to pull the data based in date.

Is there any tools available for Hadoop platform that can help achieve this.

Comment: Seen it? https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/teradata-connector-for-hadoop-command-line-edition

Comment: Have you tried `--num-mappers` option ?

Comment: This is what you are looking for - https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/53531/importing-data-from-teradata-into-hive.html

Comment: For faster performance, I have few suggestions, one is to increase the mappers split by the reliable primary key and not to write to hive table instead write to a file in HDFS. Explore the —direct option which will increase the performance.

Comment: Even with enough mappers, I think the bottleneck will be the Teradata JDBC mechanism. I do not know that it scales for that volume of data efficiently. What options do you have to move the data via named pipe from HDFS using Teradata’s Parallel Transport (TPT) utilities? Are both systems in the same data center? What’s your network backbone between them (1Gb vs 10Gb)? How are you going to validate the data after it lands on Teradata? Can you run this from the Hadoop edge node(s)?